# Tangential logistic growth function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I am new to mathematica and I ran into a problem. I am trying to imitate the method outlined in the research paper below, where a tangential logistic growth function is being found where the y value and derivative for a certain x value is the same for two logistic functions. The paper mentions that they used mathematica and I have copied the steps but in my code it does not work. In my code $f(x)$ is equivalent to $I_{II}(t)$ and $k$, $I_{III}(t)$, $I_{III}(0)$ have been replaced with k(x), g(x), h(x) respectively. When I use Reduce for certain x values to find c it only returns 0 or repeats the input and when I try to restrict the domain to 20<x<30 for NSolve it repeats the input. I am trying to figure out how to get a value for c for any value of x that makes the function look similar to the function $I_{III}(t)$ in figure A1.

[image]
[image]

```
In[1]:=
l = 65533

Out[1]=
65533

In[2]:=
f[x_] := l/(1 + (1.341*10^8)/E^(0.634834*x))
f[21]

Out[3]=
299.8077254719168

In[177]:=
g[x_] := (l + c)/(1 + ((l + c)/h[x] - 1)/E^(k[x]*(l + c)*x)) - c
k[x_] := Derivative[1][f][x]/((l - f[x])*(c + f[x]))
h[x_] := ((l + c)*(c + f[x]))/(c + f[x] + 
    E^((Derivative[1][f][x]*(l + c)*x)/((l - f[x])*(c + f[x])))*(-f[x] + l))

NSolve[g[21] == f[21], c]

During evaluation of In[230]:=
NSolve::ifun

Out[230]=
{{c -> 0.}}

In[237]:=
NSolve[g[x] == f[x] && 20 <= x <= 30, {x, c}]

Out[237]=
NSolve[
  -c + (65533 + c)/(1 + (-1 + (c + 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x)) + 
           E^((5.5789055116002*^12*(65533 + c)*x)/(E^(0.634834*x)*(
                (1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x))^2*(65533 - 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/
                    E^(0.634834*x)))*(c + 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x))))))*
            (65533 - 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x))))/
          (c + 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x))))/E^((5.5789055116002*^12*(65533 + c)*x)/
          (E^(0.634834*x)*((1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x))^2*(65533 - 
             65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x)))*(c + 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/
                E^(0.634834*x))))))) == 65533/(1 + 1.341*^8/E^(0.634834*x)) && 
   20 <= x <= 30, {x, c}]

In[235]:=
Reduce[g[21] == f[21], c]

During evaluation of In[235]:=
Reduce::inex

Out[235]=
Reduce[
  -c + (65533 + c)/(1 + (-1 + (299.8077254719168 + c + 65233.19227452808*
           E^((0.06099050691158678*(65533 + c))/(299.8077254719168 + c)))/
         (299.8077254719168 + c))/E^((0.06099050691158677*(65533 + c))/
         (299.8077254719168 + c))) == 299.8077254719168, c]
```

Comment: What is the message from the errors you get?

Comment: When I tried to do Solve[g[21]==f[21]. c], I got {{}}, so basically nothing in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using exact values and simplifying as you go, your `f` and `g` are equivalent.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

l = 65533;

f[x_] = Rationalize[l/(1 + (1.341*10^8)/E^(0.634834*x)), 0];

k[x_] = Derivative[1][f][x]/((l - f[x])*(c + f[x])) // Simplify;

h[x_] = ((l + c)*(c + f[x]))/
    (c + f[x] + E^((Derivative[1][f][x]*(l + c)*x)/
            ((l - f[x])*(c + f[x])))*(-f[x] + l)) // 
   FullSimplify;
```

**EDIT:** move the definition of `g` after the definitions of `h` and `k`. This will store a simpler form of the definition for `g`. However, it doesn't change the result.

```
g[x_] = (l + c)/(1 + ((l + c)/h[x] - 1)/
         E^(k[x]*(l + c)*x)) - c // Simplify;
```

`f` and `g` are equivalent

```
g[x] == f[x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

**Edit 2:** As defined in your code, neither `f` nor the equivalent `g` are dependent on `c`

```
f[x]

(* 65533/(1 + 134100000 E^(-317417 x/500000)) *)

g[x]

(* (65533 E^(317417 x/500000))/(134100000 + E^(317417 x/500000)) *)
```

Consequently, you cannot use these to solve for `c`. Recommend that you double-check your definitions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried using your code for finding c when x=21, i.e. Solve[f[21]==g[21], c], but I got a blank output and a error message that Exponent is out of bounds for function Factor. I'm trying to find the value of c for when x is 21, or something similar if not possible for 21, so f[x] and g[x] only have to be the same for one point, while your last answer seems to indicate they are the same for all x-values. I'm not very sure but would appreciate if you could explain your answer further, and maybe show how I could get a numerical c-value for x=21 or something similar.